# Convert feet into inches in the angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two columns: feet and inches. I need to convert the feet column value to inches. How can I create a feet-to-inches calculation (calculator) in angularjs?

Comment: this requires nothing more than basic javascript math calculation and is not hard to research

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the number of feet x 12 to give you the number of inches. This has nothing to do with angular...

Answer (score 0):

You guys misunderstand the question. "The angular way" is to use a **Directive**, so that the calculator (which is what the OP asked for) is reusable anywhere.

Comment: so break out the juice then